# QML-maps: get coordinates when tap the screen

Tags: android, c++, qt, maps, qml

I'm making project using Qt Creator (Community) 5.5.1 with support of QML. 
I have this code:

main.qml:

```
MouseArea
        {   anchors.fill: parent
            onPressed: console.log('latitude = '+ (map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouse.x,mouse.y)).latitude),
                                   'longitude = '+ (map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouse.x,mouse.y)).longitude));
```

So when I tap the screen, the coordinates of this place on the map are shown on console. But I don't know how I can use these coordinates to position the marker on the screen where the clicked occurred. Here is the marker code:

```
MapQuickItem {
        id:marker
        coordinate:  QtPositioning.coordinate(******, ******);//stars are the coordinates
        sourceItem: Image{
            id: image
            source: "marker2.png"

        }
        anchorPoint.x: image.width / 2
        anchorPoint.y: image.height

    }
```

What can I do to position the marker on map at the coordinates where the click occurred? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set the `coordinate` of `marker` in the `onPressed` handler.  Something like the following:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtLocation 5.5

Map {
    id: map
    plugin: Plugin {name: "osm"}
    zoomLevel: (maximumZoomLevel - minimumZoomLevel)/2
    center {
        // The Qt Company in Oslo
        latitude: 59.9485
        longitude: 10.7686
    }

    MapQuickItem {
        id:marker
        sourceItem: Image{
            id: image
            source: "marker2.png"

        }
        coordinate: map.center
        anchorPoint.x: image.width / 2
        anchorPoint.y: image.height / 2
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onPressed: {
            marker.coordinate = map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouse.x,mouse.y))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But if I haven't got any markers on the map and it will be new marker? How can I do?

Comment: @Khan,  is your goal to have a single marker?  Do you want it to only appear when the click occurs?  If so, how about setting the marker's `visible` to false and then set it to true in `onPressed` handle.

Comment: If you want to "create" new markers which each new click, check out [docs on dynamic object creation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html) ..or better yet, use a model (where you add the clicked locations) and [MapItemView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-mapitemview.htm)

Comment: Thank you very much! But see: marker.coordinate isn't variable. How can I use it in main.cpp? It is last question.

Comment: @Khan  I don't understand your question.  Are you looking for info on how to interact with the qml objects from c++ (if so, see the docs (like  [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html) and [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html) ).  Maybe it would be best for you to create a new question.